# `CVOpenGLESTextureCache` Am I using it wrong ？

Tags: ios, opengl-es

refer to `GPUImage`, i use frameBufferCache to reuse framebuffer.

use `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage()` to create new framebuffer

```
CVOpenGLESTextureCacheRef coreVideoTextureCache = [WDContext shareImageContext].glTextureCache;
            

            CFDictionaryRef empty; // empty value for attr value.
            CFMutableDictionaryRef attrs;
            empty = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                       NULL,
                                       NULL,
                                       0,
                                       &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                                       &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks); // our empty IOSurface properties dictionary
            attrs = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                              1,
                                              &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                                              &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
            CFDictionarySetValue(attrs, kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey, empty);

            CVReturn err = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                               (int) self->_size.width,
                                               (int) self->_size.height,
                                               kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA,
                                               attrs,
                                               &self->renderTarget);
            if (err) {
                NSLog(@"FBO size: %f, %f", self->_size.width, self->_size.height);
                NSAssert(NO, @"Error at CVPixelBufferCreate %d", err);
            }

            err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                               coreVideoTextureCache,
                                                               self->renderTarget,
                                                               NULL, // texture attributes
                                                               GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                                               self->_textureOptions.internalFormat, // opengl format
                                                               (int) self->_size.width,
                                                               (int) self->_size.height,
                                                               self->_textureOptions.format, // native iOS format
                                                               self->_textureOptions.type,
                                                               0,
                                                               &self->renderTexture);
            if (err) {
                NSAssert(NO, @"Error at CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage %d", err);
            }

            CFRelease(attrs);
            CFRelease(empty);

            glBindTexture(CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(self->renderTexture), CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(self->renderTexture));
            self->_texture = CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(self->renderTexture);
            glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, self->_textureOptions.wrapS);
            glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, self->_textureOptions.wrapT);

            glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,
                                   GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
                                   GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                   CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(self->renderTexture),
                                   0);
```

when framebuffer is no use,then return to cache for reuse later.

and in my program，i also need to decode the video, and convert YUV format pixelBuffer to RGB texture

```
CVOpenGLESTextureRef luminanceTextureRef = NULL;
                    CVOpenGLESTextureRef chrominanceTextureRef = NULL;
                    
                    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE4);
                    err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                       [WDGLContext shareImageContext].glTextureCache,
                                                                       pixelBuffer,
                                                                       NULL,
                                                                       GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                                                       GL_LUMINANCE,
                                                                       w,
                                                                       h,
                                                                       GL_LUMINANCE,
                                                                       GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                                                                       0,
                                                                       &luminanceTextureRef);
                    
                    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(luminanceTextureRef));
                    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
                    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
                    
                    if (err) {
                        WDMKLog(@"YUV Make Texture Error at CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage %d", err);
                    }
                    
                    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE5);
                    err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                       [WDGLContext shareImageContext].glTextureCache,
                                                                       pixelBuffer,
                                                                       NULL,
                                                                       GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                                                       GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA,
                                                                       w / 2,
                                                                       h / 2,
                                                                       GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA,
                                                                       GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                                                                       1,
                                                                       &chrominanceTextureRef);
                    if (err) {
                        WDMKLog(@"YUV Make Texture Error at CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage %d", err);
                    }
                    
                    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(chrominanceTextureRef));
                    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
                    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

the problem is when i have framebuffer reused from cache in other process, then the luminance or chrominance texture created by `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage` is not correct

if all framebuffer are new, not from cache ,then there is no problem.

i have no idea What does it matter about framebuffer cache， The only common point is that both use `CVOpenGLESTextureCache`.

so ,  am I using it wrong ？

i am puzzled by this question for a long time, anyone can help?  thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sorry，opengl operation was right，there were problems elsewhere.